# InvalidArgumentError while fine tuning using VGG16 with input shape as (192,192,3)

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, transfer-learning, invalid-argument

I'm using the multimodal MR image dataset. I don't understand what causes this error during training:

```py
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,4] and labels shape [9437184]    
sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
```

My code:

```
conv_base=VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(192,192,3))
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation= 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-5), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
h=model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=1,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val))
```

The shape of `X_train` is `(162,192,192,3)`.

The shape of `Y_train` is `(162,192,192,4)`.

Comment: try 'categorical_crossentropy' instead of 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

Comment: @Elizabeth, Did you tried to change loss function as per suggested above?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani Thanks. It worked

Comment: @TFer2 Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marco Cerliani. For the benefit of community providing solution here

```
conv_base=VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(192,192,3))
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation= 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
h=model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=1,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val))
```